# Google Play Web Video Player API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api, google-play, embed

Is there an API for the Google Play online video playback of content? Would the YouTube API work?

I am wanting to embed Google Play content into a website I am building.

Thank you,

Joseph Irvine

Answer (score 0):

Google Play movie purchases and rentals do also show up as YouTube videos (with a unique YouTube video ID), and so it is possible; obviously, you'd need to use oAuth2 authentication so when a user logs in, YouTube can verify that the user has the permission to see that film/TV show.

The real trick, however, is getting the right YouTube ID. They show up through search results via the search endpoint (so, for example, https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Monsters+University&key={YOUR_API_KEY} would be such a search), but that endpoint only gives you access to the "snippet" content type, which doesn't include the parameter "licensedContent" to let you know if it's a for-pay video (that parameter is found in the "contentDetails" type, which is only available from a video list call).